# How to marshall soap response to pojo?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap-client

I have a simple Spring integration project in which I connect to simple soap service 
[http://www.w3schools.com/webservic/tempconvert.asmx](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx) to convert temperature.

Here is xml that defines chain for soap service:

```
   <beans:beans
        ...
        <chain input-channel="fahrenheitChannel" output-channel="celsiusChannel">
            <ws:header-enricher>
                <ws:soap-action value="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/FahrenheitToCelsius"/>
            </ws:header-enricher>
            <ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx"/>
        </chain>

        <!-- The response from the service is logged to the console. -->
        <stream:stdout-channel-adapter id="celsiusChannel"/>

    </beans:beans>
```

and here is demo class that sends message through input channel:

```
 public class WebServiceDemoTestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/integration/temperatureConversion.xml");
        ChannelResolver channelResolver = new BeanFactoryChannelResolver(context);

        // Compose the XML message according to the server's schema
        String requestXml =
                "<FahrenheitToCelsius xmlns=\"http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/\">" +
                "    <Fahrenheit>90.0</Fahrenheit>" +
                "</FahrenheitToCelsius>";

        // Create the Message object
        Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestXml).build();

        // Send the Message to the handler's input channel
        MessageChannel channel = channelResolver.resolveChannelName("fahrenheitChannel");
        channel.send(message);
    }

}
```

It works fine and I here is response:

```
<FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/"><FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>32.2222222222222</FahrenheitToCelsiusResult></FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse>
```

Now, how can I marshall that xml response to simple pojo object?

If someone could post some code example.

Comment: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html -- FYR...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
class FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse {
    @XmlElement(name = "FahrenheitToCelsiusResult")
    private double result;

    public double getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

public class X {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String s = "<FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse><FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>32.2222222222222</FahrenheitToCelsiusResult></FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse>";
        FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse res = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(s), FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse.class);
        System.out.println(res.getResult());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I addition to Evgeniy answer, as far real ws endpoint on https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx returns XML result with xmlns attribute:

```xml
<FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com/xml/">
  <FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>...</FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>
</FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse>
```

I found that pojo should be modified (add namespace attribute to XmlElement annotation) as follows:

```java
  @XmlRootElement
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  class FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse {

    @XmlElement(
        name = "FahrenheitToCelsiusResult",
        namespace = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/" // <-- important!
    )
    private double result;

    public double getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

Regards